# responsive square to fill 100% row

Tags: html, css

i have 4 responsive squares that i create [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/josedvq/38Tnx/).

each square is set to be 25% width of his parent container. the container div of the square (square-box) is ok, but the inner div (square-content div) which is `display: table` is not getting decimal point to his width. so if the box is 100.5px width, his container will be 100px. so for 4 squares i have 2px less.

You can see at the image the empty space on the right side.[image]

Comment: wher are your codes?

Answer (score 0):

I can assume that 'empty' space is the margin gap of the parent elements.

Is this what your are looking for ?

```css
body, 
.square-box, 
.square-content,
.square-content div,
.square-content span {
    margin: 0 ;
}

.square-box {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #4679BD;
    width:100%;
}
.square-box:before {
    content:"";
    display: block;
    padding-top: 100%;
}
.square-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    color: white;
    width:100%;
}
.square-content div {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-size:40px;
}
.square-content span {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: white
}
.square-content span:nth-of-type(1) {
   background:red;
}
.square-content span:nth-of-type(3) {
   background:yellow;
    color:black;
}
```

```html
<div class='square-box'>
    <div class='square-content'>
        <div>
            <span>Box 1</span>
            <span>Box 2</span>
            <span>Box 3</span>
            <span>Box 4</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```